# Parse Razer form after an ajax post

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, c#-4.0, webmethod

I would like to send the form serialezed with an ajax call to beckend and parse it like with an object.

Right now i send every parameters in this way

```
var obj = { idSede: idSede, pickupDay: pickupDay, note: note, readyByTime: readyByTime,  closeTime: closeTime };
var json = JSON.stringify(obj);

$.ajax({
            url: "/ajaxCall/ajaxCall?handler=InsertDhlPickup",
            method: "GET",
            data: json,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });
```

But this is not confortable.

This is the serialized form, i would like to send it to backend and parse it like an object

```
__RequestVerificationToken=CfDJ8CHSQ74Ur15JqRlbHLgTj7GWgk4EqMBg9sxqngdoO3TlqphYf4D-ZFy7noKGvP8lJVcXbb8nAqIksnoXMJpXOwHqbCyThBGqigSWGPUJFRc_oP6z8dkGcl_cEX4As8mOVuFNWEdh3CtQccK_Ev32kDY&sedeCliente.Telefono1=030%206950238&sedeCliente.Citta=Roma&sedeCliente.Indirizzo=Via%20Cesare%201&sedeCliente.Cap=20200&sedeCliente.Provincia=RM&sedeCliente.Email=
```

The form is filled with razor model then in ajax post the parameter is called sedeCliente.etc
then i can't create an object with the point in the name, to parse it.

Which is the best way to parse the form as an object ?

This is what i would like to have

```
public JsonResult OnGetInsertDhlPickup(formModel formModel){
       string indirizzo = formModel.Indirizzo;
```